# debug solr response in eclipse

Tags: solr

There are some double fields in the response have values as "NaN", however, i know the indexed fields have valid values. However, in Eclipse, how to debug and where to locate the code that write the response out? Hmm...i am able to start tomcat in eclipse and invoke a request from browser, but how to debug the response and where?

I am new to solr, any of your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Run->Add Class Load Breakpoints... and add your response class name. You will hit this breakpoint when class' constructor is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yeah, i saw the Run->Add blah option now. Does this mean that i have to have the source code to be attached to the process otherwise i wont be able to debug?

Comment: Source is not a requirement if you can understand bytecode :) Seriously though, you can still set breakpoints and step through the code even without a source. See this SO post for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668910/eclipse-how-debug-without-source-jar. I'm sure you'll find much more info if you google.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mazaneicha! :) i will look into this for sure :)